# Linked images in Blazor Razor page not displaying

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I'm adding my existing images from a shared folder to my wwwroot/assets/images folder using 'Add as Link' option, Build Action: Content, Copy to output: Always

When trying to display them in my Razor page via <img src="assets/images/..." I'm getting blank..  (They do exists in the Bin folder after build)

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your startup.cs?And can you share your folder structure and  `...`  in `src` ?

Comment: can you `inspect element > Sources` and see if those files are being loaded as sources or not?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you need to make sure you contain `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your startup.cs.And make sure the route is correct.Here is a demo:

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            ...
        }
```

wwwroot:

[image]

html:

```
<img src="imgs/1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have been chasing a similar issue in my app. In visual studio, I have my images in wwwroot/Images/

In my html I have `<img src="images/1.jpg" />`

When I launch the app in debug mode, the images appear. When I publish it to a docker container, no images. So I logged in to portainer and opened the container console to check the file system. Sure enough, the images were there. Then it occurred to me. Linux folder routes are case sensitive. So I changed my html to `<img src="Images/1.jpg" />` and the images are now there.